# Property 'variableAB' has no setter method in class 'Class'

Tags: java-8, properties

I have two properties in my class. I changed the names, but one of the properties ends with two uppercase letters and the other does not.

```
private final List<String> variableAB = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> variableWord = new ArrayList<>();
```

and they both have the same getter setters:

```
public void setVariableAB(String recipients)
{
    variableAB.clear();
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(recipients)){
        variableAB.addAll(Arrays.asList(recipients.split(PARAM_SEPARATOR)));
    }
}

public List<String> getVariableAB()
{
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.variableAB);
}

public void setVariableWord(String recipients)
{
    variableWord.clear();
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(recipients)){
        variableWord.addAll(Arrays.asList(recipients.split(PARAM_SEPARATOR)));
    }
}

public List<String> getVariableWord()
{
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(this.variableWord);
}
```

When I try to set the property variableAB with

```
PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty()
```

I get the error in the title, while debugging it turns out the PropertyUtil can recognize the read method, but does not find the write method.
I thought it was a problem with the name of the varibale so I changed it to not end with two uppercase letters but it did not help. My second guess was a type mismatch in the setter parameters; however setting variableWord does not produce this error.

Comment: A property has a type. A getter for a property returns that type and a setter accept that type. Therefore, you can’t have a setter whose parameter type differs from the getter’s type.

Comment: I suspected that too, but for the other property, it does work without problem, that's what baffles me

Comment: When you use the standard introspection of the `java.beans` package, you will only get properties for the getters and the mismatching setters are ignored. Don’t know what Apache does atop it. https://ideone.com/wAo8il